# getting the CultureInfo from the existing ResourceSet

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, resourcemanager

I have a ResourceSet which I use in my code. Everything works ok, but because some of my users use RTL I need to know which ResourceSet is the active one.
I would sure be happy if after this code:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
Assembly localisationAssembly = Assembly.Load("Resources");
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.MyResource", localisationAssembly);
ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(ci, true, true);
```

I could do:

```
CultureInfo ci2 = rs.GetCultureInfo();
```

Comment: ResourceSet does not store that information, it is ResourceManager that maintains the association between culture and its associated ResourceSet.  Don't lose the information you used to create it, use a variable.  It is unclear how you use `rs` later but a `Dictionary<ResourceSet, CultureInfo>` would be a simple approach.

Comment: I just use rs.GetString("KeyName"). Thanks tho, I will look for another approach

Comment: Well, then you do have `rs` and that Dictionary can be the oracle.

Comment: Yes, I will use it the way you suggested

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans mentioned in the comment, it cannot be done because ResourceSet does not store the information.